# How do Imake my login page responsive, so that the login button doesn't disappear?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am creating a login page. However, when I reduce the screen size the login buttons disappear.

Is there a way to adapt the page to all types of domes so that the buttons never disappear?

I already changed the px to % but it didn't work either.

[DEMO](https://www.codeply.com/p/dFO2bDB4O3)

**CODE**

```
<div style="width: 100%;height: 100%;">
    <div class="mainImageBackground">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6">
                <div class="logoAndContentIntro animated slideInDown-25 delay-1s slow">
                    <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/brain-games/1042/Chess-Game.png" class="logoIntro">
                    <h1>Puribus Unum<br> blablabla blabla bla</h1>
                    <p>Welcome a world xxxxx to sdasdasdasd, improve,<br> asdasdasd and asdad blaabla
                        <br><br> asdasd asdasdas has asdasda asdasd soss asdasdsad.</p>
                    <div class="btnLoginRequest">
                        <button>Login</button>
                        <button>Exit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6">
                <div class="div1Animated">
                    <div style="width: 100%;height: 100%;display: flex;justify-content: flex-end;padding: 14.81% 7.24% 0 0;">
                        <img src="https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/gRuFFf19_xr7z1E8hJ12bkOmF2E=/0x0:1980x1320/1400x933/filters:focal(832x502:1148x818):no_upscale()/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/65613211/microsoftedgenewlogo.5.jpg" width="826px" height="608px" class="landingPageDesktop animated fadeInDown delay-1s slow">
                        <div class="imageHide">
                            <img src=""  width="100%" class="animated fadeInUp delay-1s slow">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use media breakpoints to style at a given screen size accordingly

Comment: What do you mean they disappear ? :) they can't just vanish. You mean they ' go down ' out of the screen ? You could use bootstrap classes for the buttons also. To control how they ' appear ' on each screen size.

Comment: Looks like you are using a lot of CSS to counteract Bootstrap's functionality, resulting in unexpected behaviour. Try to use Bootstrap's buildin functionality to achieve what you want and only use custom css where neccessary.

Comment: Also, you are using Bootstrap classes, but you didn't include the Bootstrap library.

Answer (score 1):

## Cause Identified

Your buttons are disappearing because of the following code.

Opacity:0 is hiding your entire Div. You need to redefine the logic.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)
.logoAndContentIntro {
    top: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    background-image: url(~/assets/home2_tablet.svg);
    background-position-y: bottom;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px 32px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
    width: 100%;
    /* opacity: 0; */
}
```

[image: Code Sample from Codeply]

[image: Snapshot with Buttons]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help ! Didn't you change anything else? I tried to change the part shown but it still doesn't appear :(

Comment: My pleasure!

Just check the code highlighted in Codeply shared by you.

Please explain your detailed requirements so that I can give your a better solution.

Comment: I tried but it didn't work :( Basically I intend that the page design adapts to any type of dimension (be responsive). Right now, when I reduce the screen, I can't see the buttons to login :(

Comment: Try this:

. logoAndContentIntro{
   opacity : 1
}

Comment: Do not worry!

We will fix your code. Share complete code.

Comment: The code is just this :( https://www.codeply.com/p/dFO2bDB4O3

Comment: Clue

.logoIntro is causing issue. Size is too large, maybe that is causing the issue.

Have to leave now, will check later. For sure.

Thanks

Comment: The worst thing is that I already tried with percentage, in fact it works, the buttons appear, but because I used low percentages

Comment: Use a smaller image and try, share the result.